# Java, Spring and OData rest service

Tags: java, spring, odata

Can you have anybody idea about, how to configure spring and Odata service using java. Please send me anybody knows about it.

Thanks
Magesh R

Comment: I think you should google it first. And if you have any specific question then ask here.

Comment: Alredy i done google for about Spring and OData but thier is no proper input about it.

Comment: Do you want to consume or produce an OData service?

Comment: I tried using Olingo lib but its not thier for spring framework configuration. Only JPA and Odata available.

Answer (score 7):

Your question is a bit vague ;-) You don't say if you want to consume or produce an OData service and if you have chosen an OData Java library / framework.

[Olingo](http://olingo.apache.org) could be a good fit for you.

- Regarding the server support, I implemented a support. See these two links: https://templth.wordpress.com/2015/02/12/implementing-a-spring-custom-namespace-for-olingo/ and https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/OLINGO-562.
- Regarding the client support, it depends on what you want to do. Having dependency injection for Olingo client classes doesn't seem necessary at a first sight.

Hope it helps you,
Thierry

Comment: And also i have some question about OData.

Comment: What is major difference between OData rest and Webservice?

Comment: What is advantage and disadvantage?

Comment: Can I deploy Sping, Java and Odata apps in IBM WebSphere?

Comment: Please can u list and give me the list of lib file names

Comment: I am getting error in applicationContext-namespace.xml for like

Comment: Multiple annotations found at this line:
 - schema_reference.4: Failed to read schema document 'http://olingo.apache.org/schema/olingo/spring-olingo.xsd', because 1) could not find the document; 2) the document could not be read; 3) the root 
  element of the document is not <xsd:schema>.
 - cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'olingo:http-handler'.

Comment: vc-complex-type.2.4.c: The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'olingo:edm-provider'.

Comment: How could be resolve this error in spring-olingo.xsd

Comment: Please can you reply this all comments as soon as possible.

Comment: Hello, I updated the code in attachment of the Olingo issue in JIRA. It should fix your problem in the schema...

Comment: Yes, sure you can use Spring, Java, OData / Olingo within Websphere since it relies on the Servlet technology. For the required lib files, please ask a new question with tag (olingo,odata) and I will answer you. It's complicated to do this within comments ;-)

Comment: When I am click this http://olingo.apache.org/schema/olingo/spring-olingo/      in the applicationContext-namespace.xml getting http 404 error. Please send me the suggestions as soon as possible today.

Comment: Please at least list me the which are the lib files used it in this framework. I raised question about required lib files for olingo-spring,odata and java

Comment: Such url is an unique identifier but doesn't correspond to a "valid" URL (that can be clicked). So it's normal that you had a 404 error when clicking on it.

Comment: You can have a look at this link for a sample Olingo service: https://github.com/apache/olingo-odata4/blob/master/samples/server/. The file pom.xml file will give you the required libraries for Olingo. You can then add the dependencies for Spring (see the pom.xml file within the contribution OLINGO-562).

Comment: <olingo:http-handler id="httpHandler" edm-provider="edmProvider"> 
still I am geting below error in applicationContext-namespace.xml  mentioned above line        
Multiple annotations found at this line: schema_reference.4: Failed to read schema document 'http://olingo.apache.org/schema/olingo/spring-olingo.xsd', because 1) could not find the document; 2) the document could not be read; 3) the root element of the document is not <xsd:schema>. cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'olingo:http-handler'.

Comment: List of jar files are I am using odata-server-api 4.0, odata-server-core 4.0 , odata-commons-api 4.0, odata-commons-core 4.0, slf4j-simple 1.7.7. Spring-bean 4.0, spring-context 4.0, spring-web 4.0 and spring-core 4.0 jars is their any problem using these all jars which you given sample app. I am using development ID for IBM RAD. - Thanks

Comment: You need to check if you have the files `spring.handlers` and `spring.schemas` within the jar olingo spring under the folder `META-INF`. These two files allow Spring to detect the XSD and namespace handler implementation.

Comment: Your list of jars seem correct. Feel free to use Maven with packaging=war. The tool will automatically put all required (transitive dependencies) within your `WEB-INF/lib` folder with the command `mvn package`

Comment: Yes you right, I tried for same spring.handlers and spring.schemas witht under the folder META-INF for like (http\://olingo.apache.org/schema/olingo/spring-olingo=main.java.org.apache.olingo.spring.config.OlingoNamespaceHandler.java)(http\://olingo.apache.org/schema/olingo/spring-olingo.xsd=main/java/org/apache/olingo/spring/config/spring-olingo.xsd)     still i am getting same error failed read schema document olingo.apache.org/schema/olingo/spring-olingo.xsd';, - Thanks

Comment: still i am unable to resole this error in applicationContext-namespace.xml in the line of <olingo:http-handler id="httpHandler" edm-provider="edmProvider"> schema_reference.4: Failed to read schema document 'olingo.apache.org/schema/olingo/spring-olingo.xsd';, because 1) could not find the document; 2) the document could not be read; 3) the root element of the document is not <xsd:schema>. cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'olingo:http-handler

Comment: I am followed your steps which your mentioned above comments. One thing I need to inform you, here I am using RAD with wepshpere and already inform you list of jars, Please can you guid me if I am anything wrong. - Thanks

Comment: Did you try to execute the unit test `SpringOlingoNamespaceHttpHandlerTest` present within the contribution?

Comment: Yes, I tried Junit testing also getting same error in applicationContext-http-handler-namespace.xml  schema_reference.4: Failed to read schema document 'olingo.apache.org/schema/olingo/spring-olingo.xsd';, because 1) could not find the document; 2) the document could not be read; 3) the root element of the document is not <xsd:schema>. cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'olingo:http-handler  - thanks